# Prove that for $n_1\neq n_2$ the measure of points in $(0,1)$ and that in their decimal representation has $1$ in $n_1,n_2$ is $\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that for $n_1\neq n_2$ the measure of points in  $(0,1)$ and that in their decimal representation has $1$ in $n_1,n_2$ is $\frac{1}{100}$ and it is measurable.

Any hint or intuition on how to do this?

Comment: Intervals are measurable, and countable unions of measurable sets are measurable. You can write the set of points in question as a finite union of half-open intervals. To see how to do this, try a small example, like $n_1=1$ and $n_2=3$. Then, try $n_1=2$ and $n_2=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many posibilities do you have for position 1? And for position 2? and for position $n_1$? and for position $n_2$? and for any position DIFFERENT for $n_1$ and $n_2$?